# Selecting from overlapping timeseries data in a data table based on processing info in a separate status table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I am dealing with bunch of different data batches of timeseries data, with each batch having a `ref_time` which is a just timestamp (in minutes) for the first time point in the batch.

Each batch has timeseries data (a `value` for a number of different parameters `param` for a sequence of time points with different offsets `fcst_time` from `ref_time`... such that `timestamp = ref_time + fcst_time`)... and the time range for each batch overlaps with that of previous batches.  So each timestamp maps onto data from several different batches.  And then there are a number (many, many) locations identified by `location`.

So my goal is to select timeseries data (for a specified `location`) from all of this which uses the most recent data (for all `param`) that is available for each timestamp.

But this is complicated by only using data from a completely-processed batch... each batch of data is processed asynchronously and only becomes 'ready' for use when all data has been received and processed.

All of this is more apparent from [this dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PkdGBhNc), with comments in there and below.

My data is stored in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data_table (
  location  text      NOT NULL
, param     text      NOT NULL
, ref_time  int       NOT NULL
, fcst_time smallint  NOT NULL
, timestamp int       NOT NULL
, value     text      NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (location, param, ref_time, fcst_time)
);
```

And I'm tracking processing status in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE status_table (
  base_name  text      NOT NULL
, version    smallint  NOT NULL
, ref_time   int       NOT NULL
, processed  bool      NOT NULL
, processing bool      NOT NULL
, updated    int       NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (base_name, version)
);
```

Here is a query to show some useful progress stats from the status table:

```
SELECT ref_time
     , max(updated) AS max_updated
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) AS processed
     , round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) * 100.0 / count(*), 1) AS percent
     , round(round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) * 1.0 / count(*), 1) * 100) AS rounded
     -- a batch is 'complete' when all files in the batch have been processed:
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) = count(*) AS complete
     -- we assume no more data coming in ('settled') when a batch hasn't been updated in a while:
     , max(updated) < (round(extract(epoch from now()) / 60) - 200) AS settled
     -- ready is when the batch is 'complete' AND 'settled':
     , (count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) = count(*)) AND (max(updated) < (round(extract(epoch from now()) / 60) - 200)) AS ready
FROM status_table
GROUP BY ref_time
ORDER BY ready DESC, rounded DESC, ref_time DESC;

ref_time    max_updated total   processed   percent rounded complete    settled ready
27793300    27805397    2       2           100.0   100     t           t       t
27793000    27805297    3       3           100.0   100     t           t       t
27794200    27805597    2       2           100.0   100     t           f       f
27793900    27805547    3       2           66.7    70      f           f       f
27793600    27805447    2       1           50.0    50      f           t       f
```

In particular, this has a crucial mapping from each `ref_time` (batch) to the `ready` status... i.e. whether each batch is ready to use.

Based on the common `ref_time` column in the status and data tables, I am then using a `LEFT JOIN` to map this `ready` status from the status table over onto the data table, to help me determine which data is actually ready for use and which is not... and I am using `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` to assign an order of preference (`rank`):

```
WITH sel AS (
  SELECT ref_time
       , (count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) = count(*)) AND (max(updated) < (round(extract(epoch from now()) / 60) - 225)) AS ready
  FROM status_table
  GROUP BY ref_time
)
SELECT
  d.timestamp
, s.ready
, d.param
, d.ref_time
, d.value
, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
    PARTITION BY d.timestamp, d.param
  ORDER BY s.ready DESC, d.ref_time DESC
)
FROM data_table d
LEFT JOIN sel s ON ( d.ref_time = s.ref_time )
ORDER BY timestamp, d.param, ready DESC, d.ref_time DESC
```

This gives an output like:

```
timestamp   ready   param   ref_time    value   rank
27793000    t       humi    27793000    55.0    1
27793000    t       temp    27793000    21.0    1
27793100    t       humi    27793000    57.1    1
27793100    t       temp    27793000    20.1    1
27793200    t       humi    27793000    62.6    1
27793200    t       temp    27793000    19.6    1
27793300    t       humi    27793300    76.0    1
27793300    t       humi    27793000    76.3    2
27793300    t       temp    27793300    18.0    1
27793300    t       temp    27793000    18.3    2
...
27793700    t       humi    27793300    61.1    1
27793700    t       humi    27793000    62.2    2
27793700    t       temp    27793300    13.1    1
27793700    t       temp    27793000    16.4    2
27793700    f       temp    27793600    17.1    3
```

Finally, I am putting the result of the above `SELECT` into a second CTE named `ref`, and using the two CTEs `sel` and `ref` to derive our final output using:

```
SELECT timestamp, param, value, ref_time FROM ref where ready='t' AND rank=1

timestamp   param   value   ref_time
27793000    humi    55.0    27793000
27793000    temp    21.0    27793000
27793100    humi    57.1    27793000
27793100    temp    20.1    27793000
27793200    humi    62.6    27793000
27793200    temp    19.6    27793000
27793300    humi    76.0    27793300
```

So what I have is a single data `value` for each for each `timestamp` and each different `param` (e.g. "temp" and "humi")... i.e. the data `value` from the most recent batch (by `ref_time`) ... but only if that batch (by `ref_time`) has a `ready` status of `true` associated with it... otherwise, use the value from the next most recent batch (by `ref_time`).

Note that each batch might have different amounts of timeseries data... it might that the most recent batch has all data required (e.g. all 72 hours for each `param`)... or it might be that the first 48 hours comes from the most recent batch, then the next 24 hours from the next most recent batch.

And it could be different per `param`... e.g. "temp" gets all 72 hours from batch 1, but "humi" gets 48 hours from batch 1, then 24 hours from batch 2 (and maybe even another 12 hours from batch 3).

I'm not sure whether I'm using the right approach at all, or whether it's much more efficient to do it another way.  I'm writing my SQL steps in the simplistic way that I think this problem through, but it may not be the best way to do it from a database point of view.

In particular, I'm finding that when I run this query on the actual database, without first selecting down to a particular `location` (e.g. for a `DELETE` operation to purge all data records that will never be selected again in a lookup for any location)... it's very slow... perhaps the `ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY` part is expensive?

How can I make it faster / more efficient / neater?

Hopefully any missing information from the above summary can be found in the dbfiddle demo linked at the top of the question.

Comment: Can you execute your slow query in your real database with EXPLAIN ANALYSE and then share the result by updating your answer ? This is to check wether your query relies on indexes or not and which may have a big impact on the performance ...

Comment: `data_table d LEFT JOIN sel s ON ( d.ref_time = s.ref_time )` can be shortened to `data_table d LEFT JOIN sel s USING (ref_time)` or even [`data_table d NATURAL LEFT JOIN sel s`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM:~:text=the%20USING%20list.-,NATURAL,-NATURAL%20is%20shorthand). Also, there's a [faster](https://dbfiddle.uk/8nbZiiC0) and clearer [`date_bin('1 minute',now(),'today')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) for things like `round(extract(epoch from now()) / 60)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Zegarek... regarding `date_bin()`, it doesn't give me an integer representing the Unix or epoch time in minutes, which is what I need.

Comment: Just pointing out there's an equivalent built-in function operating on the more adequate data type. I suspect you need an integer representation of date/times simply because you're already getting `ref_time`s as integers which dooms you to either cascade this type selection everywhere, each time casting other incoming date/times to `int`, or each time casting your `ref_time`s back to date/time. Or re-think if `int`-based `ref_time` is at all worth constant casts everywhere in the first place.

Comment: Yes, fair point, and indeed this does all start with `ref_time` being an `int` (in minutes) in the raw data. I suppose that I can make my queries a bit more readable at least, if not faster, by defining a function now_mins()... like in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fDyFEX-7).

Comment: Or make `ref_time` and `updated` actual `timestamp`s and `fcst_time` actual `interval`, digest their values through `to_timestamp(value*60)` and `*'1 minute'::interval`, and admit they were date/times all along :) Then, when the time comes to bin, compare, shift, use appropriate functions and best practices. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IOj4axou). Your `value` column would make much more sense as `numeric(3,1)`, too.

Comment: Yep, sounds sensible.  One day I might do a refactor along those lines.  Regarding `value` being better off as `numeric`, in fact it sometimes isn't... it could be some text-based code or description.  Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: That again sounds like bad design outside of a staging area. Takes more space, processes slower, also has to be cast to numeric before ordering, arithmetic, any sensible use in a function, aggregate or not. If some of the incoming values have other, distinct meaning, send them separately or separate them into another column, with [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html). [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sSo9mnH5)

Comment: I don't do any internal processing/sorting/arithmetic of data based on `value` so it doesn't affect speed?  Maybe there's a marginal gain to be made in terms of space, but at the moment space isn't really a limiting factor, and in any case I'm not sure there's much difference for storage of low precision values e.g. text `"12.3"` vs numeric `12.3` (taking account of overhead).  To squeeze a couple of MB from storage space, at the expense of far more complex queries (more difficult to read/maintain) is possibly a step too far?  Will review it though.

Comment: Hey, if it works, it works - take it as purely recreational analysis. I'd say it's way past [satisficing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing).

Answer (score 1):

The query here below should be a bit faster than yours according to their respective query plans in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ADRHhQDu) :

```
WITH sel AS (
 SELECT ref_time
      , (count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) = count(*)) AND (max(updated) < 
        (round(extract(epoch from now()) / 60) - 200)) AS ready
   FROM status_table
  GROUP BY ref_time
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (d.timestamp, d.param)
       d.timestamp
     , d.param
     , d.ref_time
     , d.value
  FROM data_table d
 INNER JOIN sel s ON d.ref_time = s.ref_time
 WHERE s.ready
 ORDER BY d.timestamp, d.param, d.ref_time DESC
```

Then the question is : can this query rely on indexes so that to boost its performance ?

In the case where you have no filter condition, you expect postgres to scan the full `data_table`, so that an index may be useless here or even less performant that an explicit sort as stated in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html) :

> The planner will consider satisfying an ORDER BY specification either
> by scanning an available index that matches the specification, or by
> scanning the table in physical order and doing an explicit sort. For a
> query that requires scanning a large fraction of the table, an
> explicit sort is likely to be faster than using an index because it
> requires less disk I/O due to following a sequential access pattern.
> Indexes are more useful when only a few rows need be fetched.

In the case where you wan to filter on a `location` values subset, then an index can be usefull.

According to the primary key you have defined on `data_table`, postgres has automatically created a multicolumn B-Tree index on `(location, param, ref_time, fcst_time)`. Filtering on a `location` values subset may conduct the query planner to use this index on its first column. But it would be better than the next indexed columns correspond to the columns used in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses of your query. In this sense, replacing the actual primary key by `(location, timestamp, param, ref_time)` in this order could make the corresponding B-Tree index more usefull for this query. But it could still be not compliant with the query clause `ORDER BY ref_time by DESC ORDER`.

The last attempt could be to create an additional index on `data_table` :

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS new_index ON data_table USING btree (location, timestamp, param, ref_time DESC NULLS LAST)
```

All these assumptions need to be tested and checked by analysing the EXPLAIN ANALYSE result of the query in the real environment.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting I will give it a try.  Regarding your comment on my question about showing the result of an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on the slow query on my actual table, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/2wp5SqwL).  It's for the same `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` statement as in [this dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/t8RMTThH)... this is a query to select records for deletion (i.e. kinda the inverse of the original question, which is to select records to show).  Key stat: `Execution Time: 206718.645 ms`.  Doesn't matter too much because I would only run this occasionally, but still horrible.